# git pull: unlink of file failed, declined to try again, finished pull, now how do I try again to pull failed file?

Tags: git

I did a git pull on a repo and a specific file was in use so git complained "unlink of [file] failed. Should I try again?" I hit No mistakenly, the git pull process finished. Now the file is no longer in use and I need to grab the updated one from the repo, but when I git pull again git tells me "already up to date". How do I go back and effectively answer "Yes" to the unlink query?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=unlink+of+file+failed.+Should+I+try+again

Comment: You can `git clean -f [file]` - it will be deleted if indeed it should no longer exist (ie, removed in the remote)

Comment: After you've resolved the "file in use" issue, then simply re-try your "git pull".

Comment: @matt Already searched.

Comment: @paulsm4 That is what I described doing im my question. Results in "already up to date" which doesn't actually appear to be the case on my end

Comment: @JaredoMills Thanks I'll try this when I get the chance.

Comment: @A__: Git "knows" which files are up-to-date, which need to be updated, and which need to be added.  Once you've cleared the "file in use" condition, another pull *SHOULD* either copy the file (if it wasn't already there) or update it (if it's missing).  A simple "git pull" (or "git pull --force") is an easy "first step".  If the file is STILL missing, or out-of-date, I'd consider `git pull --verbose` (for troubleshooting), `git reset; git pull` (try again from "clean slate") and/or `git clean -f [bad file]` (a good suggestion, just not necessarily the FIRST thing I'd try).   Good luck!